Postgres deadlock when running four unit tests
I'm running unit tests against PostgresSQL 14.11 build 1937 on Windows. Each test does the following:

Creates a temporary database on the server.

Create the tables by running a set a of SQL files.

Execute the tests


If I run the files individually they run ok. When I run three files at once everything also passes. However every time I run four files the tests deadlock. If I remove step two the tests fail but the lock up does not happen. Max connections is set to 100.
What could be causing the problem?
When the lock up occurs this is what I see in psql:
se4-unit-test=# SELECT pid, datname, usename, query, state from pg_stat_activity;
  pid  |      datname       | usename  |                               query                               | state
-------+--------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
  4868 |                    |          |                                                                   |
  4864 |                    | postgres |                                                                   |
  6972 | se4-unit-test      | postgres | SELECT pid, datname, usename, query, state from pg_stat_activity; | active
 15364 | unit-test-64df13c0 | postgres | CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Organizations(\r                      +| idle
       |                    |          |   Id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \r                             +|
       |                    |          |   Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,\r                                  +|
       |                    |          |   Created timestamptz not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)         |
 11692 | unit-test-733a213e | postgres | SELECT MAX(Version) FROM Version                                  | idle
 14620 | unit-test-290fca6b | postgres | SELECT MAX(Version) FROM Version                                  | idle
 15436 | unit-test-d85a84ce | postgres | SELECT MAX(Version) FROM Version                                  | idle
   772 |                    |          |                                                                   |
  5032 |                    |          |                                                                   |
  4816 |                    |          |                                                                   |
(10 rows)

se4-unit-test=# select * from pg_locks;
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |      mode       | granted | fastpath | waitstart
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+---------+----------+-----------
 relation   |    16394 |    12290 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 4/1250             | 6972 | AccessShareLock | t       | t        |
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 4/1250     |               |         |       |          | 4/1250             | 6972 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t        |
(2 rows)

